# Prove that if $G=\langle r, s\mid r^n=s^2=1, rs=sr^{-1}\rangle$, then $|G|\geq 2n$.

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, group-actions, group-presentation, dihedral-groups

**Source**: *Abstract Algebra* 3rd edition by Dummit & Foote.

At the end of Section 1.2, the author writes: "This kind of collapsing does not occur for the presentation of $D_{2n}$ because we showed by independent (geometric) means that there *is* a group of order 2n with generator r and s and satisfying the relations in (1). **As a result, a group with only these relations must have order *at least* 2n**."

By presentation, the author refers to $D_{2n}=\left\langle r, s\mid r^n=s^2=1, rs=sr^{-1}\right\rangle$; and by relation, the author refers to $r^n=s^2=1$ and $rs=sr^{-1}$.

**My Question**: I failed to follow this argument. For example, the dihedral group of order 8 indeed satisfies $r^8=s^2=1, rs=sr^{-1}$, which is the presentation for $D_{16}$; but clearly $|D_8|=8<|D_{16}|=16$.

What am I missing here? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: $D_8$ satisfies the relations of $D_{16}$ but they are not the irreducible relations for the presentation of $D_8$. For instance consider the relation $r^4=1$

Comment: It says "**only** these relations" so isn't $r^4=1$ excluded, since that would be another relation?

Comment: @SuzuHirose I believe by irreducible, Alessandro Cigna means a relation satisfying $r^n=1$ and $r^k\neq 1 \forall r\neq 1$ & $\forall k\in\{1, 2, ..., n-1\}$. But even with that condition, the argument is still weak.

Comment: A group with only these relations means a free group $F\langle r,s \rangle$ quotient the normal subgroup generated by $ r^8, s^2, s^{-1}rsr$. Such a group admits a surjection to $D_{2n}$ and thus has order at least $2n$.

Comment: @fyx1123581347 I don’t think any of those concepts is introduced in Chapter 1 but I’ll take your word for it. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given a presentation, there can many groups satisfying the presentation, but the presentation always define a unique group, which is in some sense the $\textbf{largest}$ one satisfying the presentation. So whenever a group of order $n$ satisfies a presentation, it only shows that the group defined by this presentation has order at least $n$, so it is a lower bound. To find an upper bound, one has to use a different kind of argument (and it's not always easy).